# PHP's SoapClient times out after twice the time of default_socket_timeout when fetching WSDL

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm using PHP's built-in SoapClient, and it needs to time out after 5 seconds. Therefore I'm using `ini_set("default_socket_timeout", 5);`. However, when fetching the WSDL it times out after 10 seconds instead. If I change the default socket timeout to i.e. 1 second it times out after 2 and so on. The actual soap calls time out after 5 seconds as expected though.

Is this a bug in PHP, expected behaviour or is there some additional setting I need to change? Using PHP 5.6.28.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you paste an example of your code, and does the same timeout behaviour happen if you use file_get_contents($wsdl)?

Answer (score 1):

There is an additional timeout setting that you will want to change: `connection_timeout` which is passed to the SoapClient in the $options array parameter.  This timeout controls how long the SoapClient waits (in seconds) to connect to the Soap service, which is what you are looking for.

Usage:

```
$soapclient = new SoapClient($uri, array('connection_timeout' => 5));
```

Once connected, `"default_socket_timeout"` comes into play and controls how long the SoapClient waits for a response.

Comment: It sounds reasonable... However it still takes 10 seconds for it to time out with the 'connection_timeout' setting no matter what i set it to.

Comment: And default_socket_timeout is still set to 5?  Strange indeed.  Is the WSDL on http or https?

Comment: Yes. It's over http to localhost.

Comment: For me, it's reproducible only with HTTP but not with HTTPS.